# Subtracting list elements from another list in R

Tags: r, lapply, subtraction

I have two lists and I want to subtract one list element wise with the other, in order to replicate a Matlab function `bsxfun(@minus, lt, lt2)`. The two lists look something like the below (edit: now works without pracma package):

```
# Code 

# First list
lt = c(list())

# I use these lines to pre-dim the list...
lt[[1]] = c(rep(list(1)))
lt[[2]] = c(rep(list(1)))

# ... such that I can add matrices it this way:
lt[[1]][[1]] = matrix(c(3),nrow=1, ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
lt[[2]][[1]] = matrix(c(1),nrow=1, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)

# Same with the second list:
lt2 = c(list())
lt2[[1]] = c(rep(list(1)))
lt2[[2]] = c(rep(list(1)))

lt2[[1]][[1]] = matrix(c(2,2,2),nrow=3, ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
lt2[[2]][[1]] = matrix(c(1,1,1),nrow=3, ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
```

Element wise subtraction would mean that that each row of an element of `lt2` would be subtracted
by the respective element of the object `lt`, i.e., lt2[[1]][[1]]  each row by 3, resulting in t(c(-1 -1 -1)).... and lt2[[2]][[1]] = t(c(0,0,0)) by  1 ... It is important to me that the list structure is maintained in the results.

Now I tried using `lapply(lt2,"-",lt)` but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the `ones` function?  Is it from any package

Comment: Sorry, it is actually from the pracma package, just creating ones. @akrun Code example should now work without pracma package.

Comment: you cannot subtract a matrix 1 by 1 and a matrix 3 by 1.

Comment: @onyambu It is supposed to result in every row of  say [1,1,1]T being subtracted by, e.g., 4, resulting in [-3 -3 -3]T.

Comment: But you cannot subtract a 3×1 matrix from a 1×1 matrix. You can rather subtract a vector of length 3 from another vector of length 1.  Whatevrr you are asking is impossible. Change those to vectors and a solution will be provided

Comment: I might have not been clear: x[[1]][[1]] = [1 1 1]T is supposed to be subtracted row wise by the respective element y[[1]][[1]] = [1]. In this case the result would be [0 0 0]T. Just the list structure of x is supposed to be maintained - I was therefore looking for a lapply solution in some way

Comment: I corrected some mistakes in the question. @onyambu

Comment: There is no mistake corrected. eg try `lt[[1]][[1]] - lt2[[1]][[1]]` and see that it cannot work

Comment: @onyambu: I did: "Element wise subtraction would mean that that each row of an element of lt2 would be subtracted by the respective element of the object lt, i.e., lt2[[1]][[1]] each row by 3, resulting in t(c(-1 -1 -1)).... and lt2[[2]][[1]] = t(c(0,0,0)) by 1 ... " - the examples here refer to the code examples.

Comment: if you are doing an elementwise subtraction then `lt1` will also have a matrix of the same dimension as lt2 or even be a vector. Also the lengths of lt1 will be the same as lengths of lt2. But this is not the case. So elementwise is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I had another mistake in the question :/

Changing the second class as.numeric worked

`lt3 = lapply(lt2[[1]],"-",as.numeric(lt[[1]]))`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are looking for something like this skeleton code which subtracts 2 lists element-wise...

```
x <- list(1,2,3)
y <- list(4,5,6)
mapply('-', y, x, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

but as noted, you need 2 identical lists (or at least R's recycling algorithms must make sense) as for example...

```
z <- list(4,5,6,7,8,9)
mapply('-',z,x,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

You might be looking for something like this where you subtract a constant from each member of the list...

```
mapply('-',y,2, SIMPLIFY= FALSE)
```

Comment: The lists are not identical in the example above. x[[1]][[1]] = [1 1 1]T is supposed to be subtracted row wise by the respective element y[[1]][[1]] = [1]. In this case the result would  be [0 0 0]T. Just the list structure of x is supposed to be maintained - I was therefore looking for a lapply solution in some way.